# My rails plugin is not putting my files in the /app and /lib direction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a rails engine which can be seen [here on github](https://github.com/JoshuaMSchultz/Rails_App_Style_Guide). This plugin uses files in its lib directory and has a controller, view, layout, and route setup as well.

When I run

```
rails s
```

locally on /test/dummy it works fine. However, when I create a new app and require it I get:

> No such file or directory @ dir_initialize -
>   ../../lib/assets/style_guide/markup/base

The plugin is not "transferring" the files in my /app and /lib directory over to the new Rails application. How do I get the plugin install the files in the rails app?

Below are some of the key files for this plugin. I am figuring whatever will move my controller over will also move the rest of the app and lib directories over. If you need to see more code you can look at [here on github](https://github.com/JoshuaMSchultz/Rails_App_Style_Guide)h

gemspec:

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)

# Maintain your gem's version:
require "style_guide/version"

# Describe your gem and declare its dependencies:
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "style_guide"
  s.version     = StyleGuide::VERSION
  s.authors     = ["Joshua Schultz"]
  s.email       = ["me@joshuaschultz.com"]
  s.homepage    = "http://quiet-citadel-4316.herokuapp.com/style_guides/index"
  s.summary     = "Rails-based Style Guide Plugin"
  s.description = "Style_Guide is a plugin used to append an automated boilerplate resource to your rails app allowing you to see/show your style guide. This work is largely based off of the idea initiated at https://github.com/bjankord/Style-Guide-Boilerplate"
  s.license     = "MIT"

  s.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0")
  s.executables   = s.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  s.require_path = 'lib'

  s.test_files = Dir["test/**/*"]

  s.add_dependency "rails", "~> 4.1.4"
  s.add_dependency "sqlite3"

end
```

/lib/style_guide.rb

```
require "style_guide/engine"

module StyleGuide



end
```

/lib/style_guide/engine.rb

```
module StyleGuide
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    initializer 'Style Guide precompile hook', group: :all do |app|
      app.config.assets.precompile += %w( style_guides.css )
      app.config.assets.precompile += %w( style.css )
      app.config.assets.precompile += %w( style_guides.js )
      app.config.assets.precompile += %w( style_guides_plugins.js )
    end

  end
end
```

/app/controllers/style_guide_controller.rb

```
class StyleGuideController < ApplicationController
  layout 'style_guide.html.erb'
  include StyleGuideHelper

  def index
    @basefiles = []   
    @patternfiles = []
    Dir.foreach("../../lib/assets/style_guide/markup/base") do |file|
      @basefiles << file if File.extname("#{file}") == ".html"
    end
    Dir.foreach("../../lib/assets/style_guide/markup/patterns") do |file|
      @patternfiles << file if File.extname("#{file}") == ".html"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Dir.foreach("../../lib/assets/style_guide/markup/base")
```

When in the host app the path `"../../lib/assets/style_guide/markup/base"` will be incorrect. You need to use the engine's root path:

```
Dir.foreach(StyleGuide::Engine.instance.root.join("lib/assets/style_guide/markup/base"))
```

What this does is return the file system path to the installation of the StyleGuide gem:

```
StyleGuide::Engine.instance.root
```

returns a `Pathname` object which you can call `join` and pass a string to join the 2 together with the platforms directory delimiter `/` in nix.

P.S. why does it need `s.add_dependency "sqlite3"`?

Comment: It doesn't. If you look on github, I removed that. But when I try to run it locally from dummy, it seems to need that. I am not skilled enough to understand what in the dummy is requiring that.

Comment: By default a rails app includes sqlite3 so I think the dummy needed it. That line should really be `s.add_development_dependency "sqlite3"`.